# Compare multiple dataframes' columns names with original one's in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, numpy, dataframe

Let's say I have a dataframe `df` with headers `a, b, c, d`.

I want to compare other `dfs (df1, df2, df3, ...)` columns name with it. I need all the `dfs`'s columns name should be exactly identical as `df` (**Please note the different order of columns names should be not considered as different column names**).

For example:

Original dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]),
                   columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

col = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

dfs:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]),
                   columns=['a', 'c', 'b'])
```

Returns `identical columns name`;

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3, 10], [4, 5, 6, 11], [7, 8, 9, 12]]),
                   columns=['a', 'c', 'e', 'b'])
```

Returns `extra columns in dataframe`;

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2], [4, 5], [7, 8]]),
                   columns=['a', 'c'])
```

Returns `missing columns in dataframe`;

```
df4 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]),
                   columns=['a', '*c', 'b'])
```

Returns `errors in dataframe's column names`;

```
df5 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3, 9], [4, 5, 6, 9], [7, 8, 9, 10]]),
                   columns=['a', 'b', 'b', 'c'])
```

returns `extra columns in dataframe`.

If it's too complicated, it's also OK returning `columns names are incorrect` for all kinds of errors.

How could I do that in Pandas? Thanks.

Comment: kindly provide sample dataframe with expected output

Comment: Updated, please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think set here is good choice, because order is not important:

```
def compare(df, df1):
    orig = set(df.columns)
    
    c = set(df1.columns)

    #testing if length of set is same like length of columns names
    if len(c) != len(df1.columns):
        return ('extra columns in dataframe')
    #if same sets
    elif (c == orig):
        return ('identical columns name')
    #compared subsets
    elif c.issubset(orig):
        return ('missing columns in dataframe')
    #compared subsets
    elif orig.issubset(c):
        return ('extra columns in dataframe')
    else:
        return ('columns names are incorrect')

print(compare(df, df1))                    
print(compare(df, df2))    
print(compare(df, df3))    
print(compare(df, df4))    
print(compare(df, df5))    

identical columns name
extra columns in dataframe
missing columns in dataframe
columns names are incorrect
extra columns in dataframe
```

For returned values:

```
def compare(df, df1):
    orig = set(df.columns)
    
    c = set(df1.columns)

    #testing if length of set is same like length of columns names
    if len(c) != len(df1.columns):
        col = df1.columns.tolist()
        a = set([str(x) for x in col if col.count(x) > 1])
        return f'duplicated columns: {", ".join(a)}'
    #if same sets
    elif (c == orig):
        return ('identical columns name')
    #compared subsets
    elif c.issubset(orig):
        a = (str(x) for x in orig - c)
        return f'missing columns: {", ".join(a)}'
    #compared subsets
    elif orig.issubset(c):
        a = (str(x) for x in c - orig)
        return f'extra columns: {", ".join(a)}'
    else:
        a = (str(x) for x in c - orig)
        return f'incorrect: {", ".join(a)}'
```

---

```
print(compare(df, df1))                    
print(compare(df, df2))    
print(compare(df, df3))    
print(compare(df, df4))    
print(compare(df, df5)) 

identical columns name
extra columns: e
missing columns: b
incorrect: *c
duplicated columns: b
```

Comment: @ahbon - so possible duplicated columns names? Is possible deduplicated first?

Comment: No duplicated columns for `df`, but it's possible for other `dfs`.

Comment: @ahbon - OK, added second condition, now testing with your sample dataframe.

Comment: Sorry, if we have `df4 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd']) `, it should not considered as `identical columns name`.

Comment: @ahbon sorry, now working, last version of my answer.

Comment: Your example data has been removed.

Comment: @ahbon - yes, because now I use your example data from question.

Comment: Sorry, one more question, is it possible to return also missing, extra, and wrong columns name while check?

Comment: @ahbon - Not so esy, need some time.

Comment: @ahbon - If columns are `columns=['a', 'b', 'b', 'b'])` need output `b` or `b,b` ?

Comment: Maybe return `duplicated columns b`?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a normal python function which uses pandas function to get columns and compare them, please see if this helps:

```
def check_errors(original_df, df1):
    original_columns = original_df.columns
    columns1 = df1.columns
    if len(original_columns) > len(columns1):
       print("Columns missing!!")

    elif len(original_columns) < len(columns1):
       print("Extra Columns")

    else:
        for i in columns1:
           if i not in original_columns:
              print("Column names are incorrect")
```